# Python multiprocessing itertools for two lists

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

Is there an easy way in Python 3 to iterate over the product of different list and to use the multiprocessing.Pool in order to speed the calculations up?

The code for the sequential calculation looks like that:

```
from itertools import product

data1 = [1,2,3,4]
data2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def main():
    for element in product(zip(data1, data2), repeat = 2):
        print(element)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Output:
(1, a),(1, a)
(1, a),(2, b)
(1, a),(3, c)
(1, a),(4, d)

(2, b),(1, a)
(2, b),(2, b)
(2, b),(3, c)
(2, b),(4, d)
...
```

Now I know that i can use the multiprocessing.Pool to parallel iterate over the product of (multiple) lists but it only supports one iterable argument:

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product

data1 = [1,2,3,4]
data2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def func(myfunc):
    return myfunc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.map(func, product(data1 ,repeat = 2))
```

As I want to add data2 and use all CPUs for the further calculation I tried several other functions like multiprocessing.starmap and functools. None of them worked for me.

My question is if you have an easy solution for this problem or do i need to think 'out of the box' and define special processes for every step. I was hoping to solve this problem with the multiprocessing.Pool as it doesn't matter in which  order the calculations are done.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me exactly what you're asking due to the user of `zip` for data1 and data2 in the first code example. What is the exact problem with using `Pool`? Do you get an error? What output do you get vs what output do you want?

Comment: Well somehow i realized that it works with zip as well: `pool.map(func, product(zip(data1, data2), repeat = 2))` My question is if there there is another way? I need the fasted implementation somehow. When i `time` the calculation it is just 20-30 % faster with more Pools than 1.

Comment: When you say more pools, what do you mean? More processes in the one Pool?

Comment: Yes i meant more processes in the Pool (4 or higher)